# centering a div with dynamic width using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div with absolute position which has a dynamic width `width:auto;` in the css style.

the content of this div is dynamic texts... which means whatever I type into an input field, it will be displayed inside this div.

when the div is empty or has only a 2-3 letters inside it, it is centered... but when there are more letters or words inside the div, the width of the div expands to show the contents and this will make the div to not to be centered anymore..

I did try `text-align:center;` in the CSS style and this did not work. I also tried `margin: 0 auto;`.

Is there any way using javascript or jquery to calculate the content of the div and center it accordingly?

OR

is there anyway, to expand the Div both right and left ways so the middle of the Div is always centered? as currently the Div expands from the right side only as there are more letters in it!

Here is my CSS for this dynamic div:

```
#BOTtext{
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    height: 16px;
    left: 47%;
    top: 140px;
    z-index: 1000000000;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you demonstrate your issue in fiddle?

Comment: You might want to have a look at the maximum recommended line length, when a line of text is too long, it's not good for readability, so I would suggest you to use a fixed width actually, not too wide, an example article would be: http://baymard.com/blog/line-length-readability

Comment: Such a high z-index is ridiculous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/AyBtT/

**Javascript**

```
$(function () {
    $("#txt").keyup(function () {
        $("#BOTtext").html($(this).val());
        adjust();
    });
    $(window).resize(adjust);
    adjust();
    function adjust() {
        $("#BOTtext").css("left", ($(window).width() - $("#BOTtext").width())/2);
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="BOTtext">Type in the text field</div>
<input id="txt"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

try with a negative `transform: translateX`

```
#BOTtext{
    position: absolute;
    top: 140px;
    left: 50%;    
    height: 16px;
    z-index: 1000000000;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;

    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);

}
```

Example on codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/isDHa/

Comment: this works like a charm.. does this work in all the browsers?

Comment: @user3454730 on all browser supporting CSS3 `transform` (not on IE<= 9)

Answer (score 0):

#### With positioning absolute/fixed you need to apply some fixed width, width auto won't work.

To be tricky, you could use min-width:

```
#BOTtext{
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 200px;
    height: 16px;
    left: 47%;
    top: 140px;
    z-index: 1000000000;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You might be looking for this

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="bot">Hello Woroorerer </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.wrapper{
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid red;
    width:450px;
}

#bot{
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    border:1px solid green;
}
```

jQuery

```
var botWidth = $('#bot').width();
var shift = botWidth/2
$('#bot').css("margin-left",-shift)
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pu4A6/

js needs to be modified as per your requirement whether on window load etc